# Bar Line Chart on Pentaho Report Designer. How show value label on point line on second Y axis

Tags: charts, pentaho-report-designer

It's possible to show value point line on bar line chart?

For example, the following chart is how is now:
[HowIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1beAP.png)

the following instead, is how i would like it:
[HowIwouldLike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOjUV.png)

Thanks very much
Patty

I tried to modify option chart but I didn't found the solutions.